# Bash matching part of string

Tags: bash, string-matching

Say I have a string like

```
s1="sxfn://xfn.oxbr.ac.uk:8843/xfn/mech2?XFN=/castor/
    xf.oxbr.ac.uk/prod/oxbr.ac.uk/disk/xf20.m.ac.uk/prod/v1.8/pienug_ib-2/reco_c21_dr3809_r35057.dst"
```

or

```
s2="sxfn://xfn.gla.ac.uk:8841/xfn/mech2?XFN=/castor/
    xf.gla.ac.uk/space/disk1/prod/v1.8/pienug_ib-2/reco_c21_dr3809_r35057.dst"
```

and I want in my script to extract the last part starting from prod/ i.e. "`prod/v1.8/pienug_ib-2/reco_c21_dr3809_r35057.dst`". Note that $s1 contains two occurrences of "prod/".

What is the most elegant way to do this in bash?

Comment: Is it possible for these strings to *not* include `prod/`? If so, then -- what is the desired behavior in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using BASH string manipulations you can do:

```
echo "prod/${s1##*prod/}"
prod/v1.8/pienug_ib-2/reco_c21_dr3809_r35057.dst

echo "prod/${s2##*prod/}"
prod/v1.8/pienug_ib-2/reco_c21_dr3809_r35057.dst
```

Answer (score 0):

With awk (which is a little overpowered for this, but it may be helpful if you have a file full of these strings you need to parse:

```
echo "sxfn://xfn.gla.ac.uk:8841/xfn/mech2?XFN=/castor/xf.gla.ac.uk/space/disk1/prod/v1.8/pienug_ib-2/reco_c21_dr3809_r35057.dst" | awk -F"\/prod" '{print "/prod"$NF}'
```

That's splitting the string by '/prod' then printing out the '/prod' delimiter and the last token in the string (`$NF`)

Answer (score 0):

`sed` can do it nicely:

```
s1="sxfn://xfn.oxbr.ac.uk:8843/xfn/mech2?XFN=/castor/xf.oxbr.ac.uk/prod/oxbr.ac.uk/disk/xf20.m.ac.uk/prod/v1.8/pienug_ib-2/reco_c21_dr3809_r35057.dst"
echo "$s1" | sed 's/.*\/prod/\/prod/'
```

this relies on the earger matching of the `.*` part up front.